# How to handle exception when user doesn't input the value and submit the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

One simple question...How to handle exception when user doesn't input the value(Optional value) and submit the form ? I'm looking for some simple way to implement..

I'm getting exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Below is my Controller

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(FormCollection Form)
        {
             int type_id = Convert.ToInt32(Form["type_id"].ToString());               
            int ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(Form["SelectedClientId"].ToString());
             DateTime Start_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Form["Start_Date"].ToString());
            DateTime End_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Form["End_Date"].ToString());
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           // var cm = new ContractManager();
            var cm = db.contracts.Where( c=>c.tb_contract_type_id == type_id ).ToList();

            return View(cm);
        }
```

Below is view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GenerateReport", "Home", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Generate-Report" }, new { id = "Form" }))
 {
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor-label">
        Client Name
    </div>
    <div id="Clients" class="editor-field">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Contracts/SelectClient.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
</div>

     <div class="editor">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cmContracts.tb_contract_type_id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("type_id", ViewBag.contracttypes as SelectList, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor-label">
         Start Date
    </div>
    <div  class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Start_Date", "", new {  data_datepicker = true })
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor-label">
        End Date
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.TextBox("End_Date", "", new {  data_datepicker = true })
    </div>
</div>
       <p>
            <input style="margin:20px auto 0px 120px; " type="submit" value="Generate" />
        </p>
}
```

Comment: What are you currently doing? Post your code.

Comment: put some code user.. and if it is optional, why to catch it :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use validation. In ASP.NET MVC this could be achieved by decorating your view model properties with Data Annotation attributes. Let's take an example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This value is absolutely required")]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

The Required attribute is self-explanatory. Then we could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // there was a validation error => redisplay the view
            return View(model);
        }

        // success
        return Content("Thanks for submitting the form");
    }
}
```

and finally you could have a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeValue)
        @Html.EditorForFor(x => x.SomeValue)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SomeValue)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

In this view the `ValidationMessageFor` helper will display the associated error message if validation fails on the server.

And if you want to hanle more complex validation rules with inter-dependent properties I would recommend you taking a look at [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which provides a very intuitive and powerful way to write complex validation rules, it has a [`great integration with ASP.NET MVC`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and offers an easy way to [`unit test your validation logic`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is not throw exceptions, but validating user input with [validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This way you can handle anything wrong with user input before getting to your logic proper.

**Edit:** since your problem is that an optional field is throwing null reference exceptions, you should check whether its value is null before using it. You could do something like this:

```
string value = foo.Value;
if (value == null) value = string.empty;
```

Of course, you should do it on the relevant property, and using the correct type if it's something other than `string`. You could then use the `value` variable instead of using the control's property directly.